# Cypher: Returning node relationships and properties for all nodes in a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Currently I'm running personalized PageRank over a set of nodes. I want to take the top `n` nodes and `RETURN` all relationships between these nodes *in addition* to the resulting PageRank score for each node and a set of properties for each node.

Right now I'm managing to `RETURN` the start and end nodes of the relationships, but I'm unable to figure out how to also `RETURN` the scores and any additional node properties.

My query is as follows:

```
 MATCH (p) WHERE p.paper_id = $paper_id
 CALL algo.pageRank.stream(null, null, {direction: "BOTH", sourceNodes: [p]})
 YIELD nodeId, score
 WITH p, nodeId, score ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 25

 MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = nodeId
 WITH collect(n) as nodes
 UNWIND nodes as n
 MATCH (n)-[r:Cites]->(p) WHERE p in nodes
 RETURN startNode(r).paper_id as start, collect(endNode(r).paper_id) as end
```

In the second block of code I `collect` the matched nodes `n` in order to then find all relationships between nodes in that collection later on. However, including `score` in the `WITH collect(n) as nodes` line results in `score` being used as the indexer when I want to somehow pass it in separately (is this allowed?).

The output format is not important since I can properly format it server side.

Comment: Just return the whole node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) can help here, you can use `apoc.algo.cover()` to get all the relationships between a set of nodes.

As for bringing the score along, it would probably be best to extract from the collected nodes a [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) which includes the score:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE p.paper_id = $paper_id
 CALL algo.pageRank.stream(null, null, {direction: "BOTH", sourceNodes: [p]})
 YIELD nodeId, score
 WITH p, nodeId, score ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 25

 MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = nodeId
 WITH collect(nodeId) as ids, collect(n {.*, score}) as nodes
 CALL apoc.algo.cover(ids) YIELD rel
 RETURN nodes, collect(rel) as rels
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thanks again.